# Changing the URL title while serving a PDF file

Tags: php, nginx, pdf, download

I have a simple PHP file download script,

```
<?php

$file = sprintf("/home/data/files/%d", intval($_GET['id']));
if (! file_exists($file))
{
    die("no such file");
}

if (str_ends_with($_GET['name'], ".pdf"))
{
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
}
else
{
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $_GET['name'] . "\"");
}

header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

It works fine, but in the browser the title isn't changed

[image]

I'm not sure if there's a way to change the "files.php" title in browser. Does anyone know?

Comment: Look at rewrite rules. Not clear what server you are running. Solutions will vary by software (nginx, apache, iis, etc.)

Comment: I bellive you need use rewrite url, some like url 127.0.01:6403/arq.pdf then will redirect to your script 127.0.0.1:6403/file.php?id=arq.pdf

Comment: @MárcioRossato Rewrite worked for me

Comment: @daisy, is your problem solved then?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, I created a nginx rewrite rule to forward /files/${id}/${name} to files.php?id=$1&name=$2 and the title is successfully changed

Comment: Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer should not be hidden in the comments Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because comments aren't searchable and you can't get reputation points for votes on them. Please take the [tour] if you need a reminder of how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works (although your rep level suggests you should know by now!). The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Make sense, just created an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MárcioRossato was right, the tab title is determined by filename. The solution is quite simple, use a rewrite rule to make RESTful pattern work.

```
    location /files/ {
        rewrite /files/(.*)/(.*) /files.php?id=$1&name=$2 last;
    }
```

Therefore I can use `/files/ID/Desired Name of PDF file.pdf` to access the file while make the title correct.